# Laravel 5.5 api authorization with API Token

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to authenticate our user using the API token,

Here is my code `config/auth.php` code

```
  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

My `Api.php` is like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['subdomain_setup','auth::api'],'prefix'=>'v1'], function () {
    Route::get('getCoupons','Api\CouponAPI@getCoupons');
});
```

Now I am getting this error while accessing my api URL

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause'
>   (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` =

Comment: does your users table have a token column? are you sure it shouldn't be another table?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes my users table have api_token column

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have run Passport migration and `['guards']['api']['driver']` set to passport in `config/auth.php`, and updated the configuration cache

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session', 
        'provider' => 'users', 
    ], 

    'api' => [ 
        'driver' => 'passport', 
        'provider' => 'users', 
    ], 
],
```

Comment: 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

Answer (score 2):

You must alter table to add a 'api_token' field.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');

    //Add api_token field
    $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();

    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: additional instructions on setting up api tokens in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#database-preparation

Answer (score 1):

**Clear the cache :**

**Clear Application Cache**
Run the following command to clear application cache of the Laravel application.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**Clear config cache**
You can use config:clear to clear the config cache of the Laravel application.

```
php artisan config:clear
```